# Cx_freeze is not working on Win 10 with Python 3.6.2

Tags: python, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I am starting to learn a bit about Python. I am trying to convert Python Tkinter app into exe file. Converting to exe works fine when Tkinter is not involved. I tryed sample file of setup.py and Tkinter app that you can find on official website of cx_Freeze [http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html] but still geting a lot of errors [like: `KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'`] in CMD when runing build command. On official website is stated that Python 3.6 is supported.

Here is official example of setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('app.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='simple_Tkinter',
      version='0.1',
      description='Sample cx_Freeze Tkinter script',
      executables=executables
      )
```

And here is official example of test Tkinter app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try:
    from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, BOTTOM
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, BOTTOM

root = Tk()
root.title('Button')
Label(text='I am a button').pack(pady=15)
Button(text='Button').pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cx_freeze you could try and use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) it will do the exact same job you are trying to accomplish.

From pip go ahead and type
 `pip install pyinstaller` and then in your programs directory run `pyinstaller yourprogram.py`

Comment: I says support up to Python 3.5

Comment: You may try to use the development version , it's unstable though. But it wouldn't hurt to try it

Comment: It is working, although I get also some warnings in CMD. Is there a way a can get just one file?

Comment: pyinstaller.py filename.py --onefile

Comment: Not working. I get one file but it doesn't open GUI. And also it gives me console, although it is .pyw file.

Comment: What are the errors you are receiving when freezing the file?

Comment: Also make sure you are running the exe from the **dist** sub directory

Comment: 18 WARNING: Internal error: early pywin32 import was introduced. 10800 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\family\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe. A lot of something similar.

Comment: @Slit are you running it from the dist sub

Comment: Yes I am running it from dist sub where I have only one app.exe file, because I enter --onefile flag